# Autolayout Buttons not correct

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-autolayout

[Ipad Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i451i.png)
[Iphone Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls2f5.png)

I'm having trouble with auto layout with iPad buttons fitting like the buttons on the iPhone. Any suggestions?

Comment: please show your constraints or share demo project ....

Comment: are you using stackView ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pTllLSfbgrSFnm88V9RtjIT4pK0K8of0?usp=sharing

Comment: No I'm not using a stackview

Comment: i run your project ... so what do you want ? please elaborate

Comment: I just want the buttons to look correct on the iPad just like the iPhone. It's not lined up correctly and im not sure how to fix that. Can I just a stackview to make it correct on the iPad?

Comment: iphone look is perfect ?

Comment: you are talking about facebook , instagram and website button ?

Comment: Yes to me it looks fine. & Correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your buttons in `stackView` like this

[image]

here is the [project](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qtZQj6jsXrQRRdouL1sDTmQibyPwUt5O?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you I sent a request to view it!

Comment: access granted  to you

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: you are welcome :) .. i also sent you an email .. check that out